# SCCM Query to retrieve disposed assets in ServiceNow

Tags: servicenow, sccm

We have SCCM integrated with ServiceNow and I'm looking to make a device collection containing assets that are in a state or substate of disposed/retired/pending disposal.

Wondering if there is a way to create a membership query within SCCM to pull this information from ServiceNow and add them into a collection I've made.  Another admin has a process where once a month he runs a query in ServiceNow, exports the output list and runs a script against that list to remove devices from AD, Intune and Azure.  I live in SCCM more and am looking to get this query for my collection in place where I can review these devices more frequently.

I'm not finding much elsewhere so far, but figured I'd drop a post here while I continue my search

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at custom device properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/develop/adminservice/custom-properties

You could, for example, create a similar process as you admin colleague where you read the current state of the machine from ServiceNow and write a custom property for it in MEMCM. This enables you to create a dynamic collection membership rule based on that property.